# Redirect in Traefik from one domain to another

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, kubernetes-ingress

According to the [Traefik 1.7 documentation](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/v1.7/configuration/backends/kubernetes/) you should be able to have Traefik perform a 302 redirect using:

- `traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/redirect-regex`
- `traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/redirect-replacement`

My goal is to simply remove the `www.` from the address.

This is what I've tried, but I get a 404 service not found.

```yaml
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: www-redirect
  namespace: public
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/redirect-regex: ^https?://www.example.com/(.*)
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/redirect-replacement: https://example.com/$1
spec:
  rules:
  - host: www.example.com
```

Unfortunately the documentation isn't explicit on *how* to use them. At the time of writing the only google hit on this is the documentation (above).

My current work around (assuming it'll help explain the question) is to route `www.` traffic to nginx which returns a 302.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.example.com;
    return 302 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

This seems like overkill.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was having the same issue and ended up making it work with:

```
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: www-redirect
  namespace: public
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/preserve-host: "true"
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/redirect-permanent: "true"
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/redirect-regex: "^https://www.(.*)"
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/redirect-replacement: "https://$1"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - "example.com"
        - "www.example.com"
      secretName: example-tls
  rules:
  - host: example.com
  - host: www.example.com
```

Basically I needed both rules.

As a side note, I also start the trafik pod with the following flags:

```
args:
   - --api
   - --kubernetes
   - --logLevel=INFO
   - --entryPoints=Name:https Address::443 TLS
   - --entrypoints=Name:http Address::80 Redirect.EntryPoint:https
   - --defaultentrypoints=https,http
```

Comment: As an aside, we had a lot of trouble with the `--kubernetes` flag related to namespacing, highly recommend using a config file instead.